# Delphi 2006 always stops working when closed on Vista

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, delphi-2006, data-execution-prevention

Whenever I stop the Galileo IDE from Delphi 2006 under Vista, I get

> **Microsoft Windows**
>
> Borland® Developer
>   Studio for Windows has stopped working
>
> A problem caused the program
>   to stop working correctly. Please
>   close the program.
>
> [Close the program]

followed by some dialog by data execution prevention. Even excluding the program from DEP doesn't help.

How can I prevent this from happening?

**Reacting on answer**: Changing to another version of Delphi is not an option, as we develop a framework for our customers that has to run on Delphi 7 - 2007. Our main customers use Delphi 2006. Delphi 2009 is not yet been decided upon, as we have tons of code that has to be ported to unicode. We have to do extensive testing under Delphi 2006, no way around that.

Comment: I don't know.  I get Quicktime errors most times I close MS Office apps, Netbeans, or Google Chrome.  No solution in sight.  :-(  Probably just one of those things you need to get used to when running Vista.

Comment: With regard to your reaction to my answer, there's nothing in there that should preclude you from updating to D2007.  It's ABI-compatible with D2006 (you can exchange DCUs without needing to rebuild) and there aren't any breaking changes in the source like D2009.  And if you're already having to support stuff all the way back to D7, then you're aware of all the little backwards-compatibility tricks already.  You really ought to consider it.  It's worth upgrading just for the stability and memory leak fixes.

Comment: We run d2007, but we are forced to extensively run D7, D2005, D2006 to pass customer enforced tests. It just is not a solution not to run D2006.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99.954% of all shutdown errors in Delphi are caused by a poorly written component or expert.  Do you have components that you think might be the problem?

You can try removing component sets and other plugins one at a time and see if that reveals the culprit.  Or you could try starting a second instance of the IDE and attach it to the first and use the debugger to see if it reveals any clues as to what is causing the problem.

Comment: and 57% of all statistics are made up :)

Comment: Really?  I heard it was 73%. ;)

Comment: Can you tell me how I attach one IDE to the other to debug, please? I tried removing all my components, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with this specific issue, but I do know that D2006 had tons of stability problems in general, leaked hundreds of megs of memory and crashed on me very frequently.  You ought to upgrade, to D2009 if you can, or D2007 if the requirement to convert all your code to Unicode would just be too big of a hurdle.  Both were written specifically with Vista support in mind, while 2006 wasn't.

Comment: I know that, thank you. It is good advice. Only our customers don't want to do so. Banks in Switzerland are not moved easily, and we develop a framework for Delphi that has to be available under Delphi 7 - Delphi 2007.

Comment: Then at least upgrade to D2007.  All your old code will still be compatible, and the stability's a lot better.

Comment: +1 -- Upgrade to D2007 if at all possible.  You shouldn't experience any pain in this conversion, outside of any version specific defines which would need to be tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have GExperts installed? I suspected that when I had D2006 shutdown problems. It's not just a vista problem. It just manifests itself differently in xp.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all open projects before shutting down (Close All from the file menu).

I had a similar problem with D2006 under XP, and closing everything seems to prevent it (some sort of race condition?)

Note: We don't use many third party components.